# mongodb order/$sort by array entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

the item schema :

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
   name: {type : String},
   possibleorders: [{
       name: {type : String},
       value: {type : Number}
   }]
})
```

How do I order/$sort the items by a possibleorder's value with a specific name ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using aggregate framework .

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$possibleorders"}, 
  {$sort: {"possibleorders.name":1}}, 
  {$group: {_id:"$_id",name:"$name", possibleorders: {$push:"$possibleorders"}}}
]);
```